# AngularJs number count in table

Tags: angularjs

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Movie Title</th>
    </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="mov in movie | pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize | filter:searchText" data-ng-show="showSuccessMessage" data-ng-click="selectMovie($event,mov)" data-ng-class="{'selected':selectedMovie.film_id===mov.film_id}" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                {{mov.title}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Aboe code is work properly but how can i count the number and display in **No**??

Result
[image]

Comment: did you speak of `$index`? it's a variable defined inside `ng-repeat`, it gives you the actual index of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Movie Title</th>
        </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="mov in movie | pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize | filter:searchText" data-ng-show="showSuccessMessage" data-ng-click="selectMovie($event,mov)" data-ng-class="{'selected':selectedMovie.film_id===mov.film_id}" style="cursor: pointer;">
                <td>
                   {{ $index + 1 }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{mov.title}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: still you need explanation ,, go through this http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$index` to get the index of the element in an array. It starts with 0. So you can print using `$index + 1`